# What is the difference between has_one and belongs_to in active record associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-activerecord

I'm new to active record, I want to know the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to` in associations.

Can anyone explain with a good example?

I want examples for `has_one` associations without using `belongs_to` in the second model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in where the foreign key is stored.

So for example if a `post` belongs to a `user`, the post table will have a column `user_id` so the post knows which user it *belongs to*.

`has_one` only makes methods like some_user.post available.

See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Is+it+a+belongs_to+or+has_one+association%3F

Comment: Thank you. The link clarifies my doubts.